# Merge two objects React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, object

Would need help merging two objects. Both are downloaded from Firebase Firestore in a mobile application.

```js
Object 1
Object {
  "Date": "2021-04-06",
  "Store1": "199",
  "Store2": "249",
  "Store3": "159",
  "Updates": 4,
}

Object 2
Object {
 "Store2": Array [
   "Store2", 
     "Object {
       "latitude": 5,
       "longitude": 180,
      },
  ],
 "Store1": Array [
   "Store1", 
     "Object {
       "latitude": 55,
       "longitude": 120,
      },
  ],
 "Store3": Array [
   "Store3", 
     "Object {
       "latitude": 43,
       "longitude": 156,
      },
  ],
}
```

And I want to merge Object 1 into Object 2, so the result looks something is like this.

```js
Object 2
Object {
 "Store2": Array [
   "Store2",
   "249", 
     "Object {
       "latitude": 5,
       "longitude": 180,
      },
  ],
 "Store1": Array [
   "Store1",
   "199", 
     "Object {
       "latitude": 55,
       "longitude": 120,
      },
  ],
 "Store3": Array [
   "Store3", 
   "159",
     "Object {
       "latitude": 43,
       "longitude": 156,
      },
  ],
}
```

My next step for this is to print a list on the screen something like this

```
Store1  199Kr  "Geo point"
Store2  249kr  "Geo point"
Store3  159kr  "Geo point".
```

But I don't get to the merging of the data. Anyone who can help me?
I have the opportunity to influence the database from which the data is retrieved, but since other functions are built around this structure, it is a secondary alternative.
Can add that I really do not know much about either database/Firebase/JavaScript etc, so be kind :)

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the code below can help you:

```
const obj1 = {
  "Date": "2021-04-06",
  "Store1": "199",
  "Store2": "249",
  "Store3": "159",
  "Updates": 4,
}

const obj2 = {
  "Store2": [
    "Store2", 
      {
        "latitude": 5,
        "longitude": 180,
       },
   ],
  "Store1": [
    "Store1", 
     {
        "latitude": 55,
        "longitude": 120,
       },
   ],
 "Store3": [
    "Store3", 
      {
        "latitude": 43,
        "longitude": 156,
       },
   ],
 }

 //merging
for (let [key2, value2] of Object.entries(obj2)) {
  for (let [key1, value1] of Object.entries(obj1)) {
    if(key1 === key2){
      value2.push(value1)
    }
  }
}

//printing on the screen
for (let [key2, value2] of Object.entries(obj2)) {
  console.log(key2 + ' ' + value2[2] + 'Kr "Geo point"')
}
```